# What should be the correct code in order to get the factorial of n?

Tags: python, numbers, factorial

```py
n=int(input("Enter a number: "))
p=1
for i in range(n):
    p*=i
print(p)
```

I wanted to find out the factorial of a number but I always get 0 as output.

Comment: range starts from 0, so you multiply by zero at start

Answer (score 0):

The factorial of a number is the product of all the numbers from 1 to that number. However, in your code, you are starting the loop from 0 and then multiplying the product by the loop variable. This means that the product will always be 0 because any number multiplied by 0 is 0.

You can change the starting value of the loop variable to 1 instead of 0. This way, the product will be initialized to 1 and then multiplied by the numbers from 1 to n, which is the correct way to calculate the factorial of a number.

```py
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
p = 1
for i in range(1, n+1):
  p *= i
print(p)
```

You could also just use the math library which is built-in.

```py
import math

n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
p = math.factorial(n)
print(p)
```